# How to define a set with elements from one of number sets?

Tags: notation

If I want to define a set $A$ by an equation $\sqrt{x}$, but only for real numbers $R$, how it will be correct to define:

$$A = \{x:\sqrt(x),x\in R\}$$

or

$$A = \{x:\{x:\sqrt(x)\}∩R\}$$

or

$$A = \{x:\sqrt(x)\} ∩R$$

Comment: I suggest just words: "the set of all real numbers with real square roots". Those are just the nonnegative reals. In any case be careful with the square root sign. That always means the nonegative root of a nonnegative real, and should be avoided for complex arguments.

Comment: @EthanBolker, "the set of all real numbers with real square roots" can be interpreted as a union of a set of real numbers and real roots, and hence a set of real numbers, since a set of real roots is a subset of a set of real numbers. That's why formalism is more important than just words

Comment: We have to agree to disagree there. All three of your formal statements are awkward and hard to read. No one I know would misinterpret the words I suggested. Formalism is important sometimes but not always.

Comment: @EthanBolker 1) "are awkward and hard to read" - but I am asking about the correctness of formalism and not about hardness to read or awkwardness that is subjective. 2) "No one I know would misinterpret the words I suggested" - this is not an argument at all. And also today You know me, so this statement is already wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by “an equation $\sqrt{x}$”? Furthermore, all three of your displayed proposals are ill-formed. The notation $\{x:\ldots\}$ means “the set of all $x$ such that …,” so what goes after the colon has to be the syntactic equivalent of a complete sentence. But yours are all mere expressions (so noun phrases missing a verb). Do you mean something along the lines of $\{\sqrt{x}:x\in {\bf R}\}$?

Comment: Let A = { y∈R : y = √x and x∈R}, Then A is the set of all real numbers whose square is also a real number. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum, yes, not an equation, but an expression. ${\sqrt{x}:x∈R}$ looks uncommon for me, but seems to be correct

Comment: @MichaelCarey, You probably have been confused of my wrong usage of equation word, since what You defined seems to be a set of sets (pairs) $x$ and $y$, but in such case, in my books it writes next way: $\{(x,y):y=\sqrt(x)\}$, so it will be $\{\{0,0\},\{4,2\},...\}$. I meant one variable, and not an equation, however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *equation* is a formula of the form $P=Q$, where $P$ and $Q$ are *terms* in some formal language. $\sqrt x$ is a *term* or *expression*, not an equation.

To define a set by an equation, you can use set operations like $\cap$, $\cup$, and $\setminus$, or set-builder notation. Given a logical formula $\phi$, the notation $\{x:\phi(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\}$ means "the set of all $x$ such that $\phi(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is true." For example, $\{x:\forall y\neg(y\in x)\}$ is the set of all sets which contain no elements - i.e. the set containing only the empty set. I would caution that the use of set-builder notation for *arbitrary* formulas tends to lead to paradoxes (the most famous example being [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).) For this reason, mathematicians typically require the lefthand side of the expression to specify that $x$ is an element of some known set, as in $\{x\in X:\phi(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\}$. *If* $\{x:\phi(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\}$ is a set, then $\{x\in X:\phi(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\}=X\cap\{x:\phi(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\}$. For convenience, we sometimes omit bits of notation, such as writing $\{x:x^2<2\}$ in place of the more precise $\{x\in\Bbb R:x^2<2\}$.

Some general identities/conventions for setbuilder notation are:

- $\{x\in X:x\in Y\}=X\cap Y$.
- $\{x:\phi\land\psi\}=\{x:\phi\}\cap\{x:\psi\}$.
- $\{x:\phi\lor\psi\}=\{x:\phi\}\cup\{x:\psi\}$.
- For a function $f:X\to Y$, the set $\{y\in Y:(\exists x\in X)(\phi(x)\land y=f(x))\}$ is often shorthanded as $\{f(x)\in Y:\phi(x)\}$ or even $\{f(x):\phi(x)\}$.
- Sometimes we'll write $\{y\in Y:y=g(x)\land x\in X\}$ instead of $\{y\in Y:(\exists x\in X)(y=g(x))\}$ (actually, that's shorthand for $\{y\in Y:\exists x(x\in X\land y=g(x))\}$.)
- For logical formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$, we sometimes write $\{\phi(x):\psi(x)\}$ in place of $\{x:\phi(x)\land \psi(x)\}$. This is implicit in $\{x\in X:x\in Y\}=\{x:x\in X\land x\in Y\}$.

In your case, for maximum formality you would probably want to write $A=\{y\in \Bbb R:(\exists x\in\Bbb R)(y^2=x)\}$. However, as others have pointed out in comments, $\{\sqrt x:x\in\Bbb R\}$, $\{y\in\Bbb R:y=x^2\land x\in\Bbb R\}$, $\{y:y=\sqrt x,x\in\Bbb R\}$ all work.